# Android - Set Default Spinner Themes

Tags: android-layout, android, android-button

I'm new to Android development.

I'm using drag and drop to pull down a default spinner onto my layout.
However, the default is not the one I see everyone using with the triangle on the bottom right.

An example of what I see is:
http://www.mkyong.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/android-spinner-demo1.png

Whereas what I'm looking to achieve is this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/X82Ld.png

Is it a styling issue?

---

Apologies for ripping off other people's images, I don't have enough rep for uploading my own images.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Are you using an emulator or an actual device? Try it on an actual device and it'll look like what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried it on the actual device but it still stays the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've Solved my issue by setting the Theme of the application/activity to Holo.Light. Hope this helps other people in the process.